# Create User in Cognito User Pool from Private Subnet using AWS SDK Node.js

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-cognito, amazon-vpc

I am using two private subnets to deploy lambda functions. I want to access cognito user pool to create user from deployed lambda function in private subnets using aws node.js sdk. Currently there is no VPC endpoint to access cognito.

Is there any ways to access cognito user pool to create a user from private subnet without using a NAT gateway??